# VBA: set a default NumberFormat before adding the object that uses it

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting, default-value, label

I have a situation where I am adding and removing trendlines from a chart *very* often. At certain points in time I have to capture the equation of the trendline from the datalabel. For accuracy and significant figures and consistency I want the datalabel to be in scientific format. (ie "0.0000E+00)

Changing the DataLabel.NumberFormat when I want to capture the datalabel is very frustrating because I have to insert a wait time so the datalabel can update before I can capture it.

Is there something I change perhaps in the chart object so that all new trendlines already have the scientific number format? Or perhaps in the Workbook_Open() sub I could change the default value of the NumberFormat to be my format?

Here is a relevant example part of my code.

```
Sub AddLinear()
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, Forward:=0, _
    Backward:=0, intercept:=0, DisplayEquation:=1, DisplayRSquared:=0, Name:="Linear"
End Sub

Sub TrendlineEqn()
  Dim t As Trendline
  Dim eqn As String
  Set t = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)
  t.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.0000E+00"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  eqn = t.DataLabel.text
  eqn = Replace(eqn, "y= ", "")
  Range("A1").Value = eqn
End Sub

Sub Graph()
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
  Call AddLinear
  Call TrendlineEqn
End Sub
```

My actual code only differs by many more trendlines, and removing them immediately after. Once I settle on which trendline I want as my final answer, I do the above.